# Find the first N elements of a list, until a condition is satisfied

Tags: python, list

I have a list of objects, and I want to take the beginning of the list up until the first object that meets a simple condition (like `imp[1] == 'conversion'` when `imp` is some element in the list).

An easy way would be: initialize a new list, iterate through the original list, and at each step append the current element and check the condition on the current element. If the condition is not satisfied then continue, and if it is satisfied then break.

```
new_list = []
for ele in old_list:
    new_list.append(ele)
    if condish(ele):
        break
```

But this seems inefficient in memory, runtime, and code (the big three!).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this:

```
for idx, el in enumerate(your_list):
    if satisfies_condition(el):
        return your_list[:idx]
```

which will save you the cost of creating a new list in memory.

Or you can use `itertools.takewhile`

```
return list(itertools.takewhile(not_condition, your_list))
```

Comment: It seems you forgot your `enumerate`

Answer (score 6):

There is `itertools.takewhile` which should satisfy your need.  Of course, here you need to *negate* the condition in your original post so that you break when the condition is met...

```
itertools.takewhile(lambda ele: not condish(ele), old_list)
```

If you want more flexibility and control (e.g. you also want to take the first element that doesn't meet the condition), it might be worth considering a generator function:

```
def take_until(iterable):
    for item in iterable
        yield item
        if condition(item):
           return
```

then you use it like this:

```
for item in take_until(old_list):
    ...
```

This avoids building a list that you don't really need/want and gives you an iterable instead.

Comment: @iCodez -- Right, which is why I said "If you want more flexibility and control (...), it might be worth considering a generator function"